# Did my 11 month old just ruin my Ubuntu installation via the screen unlock password prompt?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, lock-screen, screensaver

My 11 month old son is obsessed with laptops and I occasionally let him play around with my Ubuntu laptop while the password protected screensaver is running. Aside from potential hardware damage, I'm not sure if there are other reasons why I shouldn't allow him to do this? Up until today the worst I had seen happen was that Ubuntu was a little bit sluggish when I eventually unlocked the screen--apparently a handful of long incorrect password attempts can take a toll?

Today disaster struck and I'm hoping someone can help. Ever since my son performed his latest round of key mashing while the screensaver was locked in place, my standard input is very messed up. All of my software seems to run fine and I can type into a browser with the same performance I would normally expect. However, any time I try to type text into a terminal or something terminal based (like Vim), there are frequent pauses followed by multi-second delays before what seems to be the correct text appears. It has nothing to do with the Universal Access Typing settings since I verified that those are unchanged and the unwanted behavior is somewhat irregular as it feels like keystrokes only start to lag when some unseen buffer fills up every few seconds.

If anyone has any ideas for troubleshooting, I would be very grateful! I've restarted my machine many times and the unwanted behavior continues. What could he have done through the locked screen?

Thanks!

Comment: Buy your son his own children's tablet to play with, and don't train him to smash keys on your laptop. They can be had for less than $50.

Comment: Wooden blocks are good, too. Better for motor skill development, and they handle drool better than electronics. Kids make everything *sticky*.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: " I've restarted my machine many times and the unwanted behavior continues. "

Comment: What screen saver do you use?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm actually just using Ubuntu's built-in "Lock Screen after screen turns off" feature in the "Brightness & Lock" widget.

Comment: @heynnema agreed--lesson learned! now its just a matter of reverting whatever change he made.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that ever since this mysterious change took place, the password screen to wake the computer from its sleep now looks somewhat different. There's also a blue stripe at the top of the screen that is sometimes seen before the laptop goes back to the password entry screen.

Comment: There's a good chance that your son changed the desktop environment by clicking on the little icon near the login prompt, popping up the menu, and selecting some other DE. Make sure the login screen is focused on your name, use the up/down arrows to change that if required, then click on the little icon and select the DE of your choosing, then log in. Check that and report back.

Comment: @heynnema I think your suggestion led me to resolve the problem although perhaps in a different way than we expected. I started poking around at the user login screen and I actually couldn't find a way to change my DE (maybe I only have one DE installed so the option isn't there?). I confirmed that I was still using Gnome 3/Unity upon login. However, by poking around the login screen at the subtle options that **did** exist, I noticed there was one for Screen Reader. I'm not 100% sure that I had it enabled but once I toggled it off and logged back in everything seems back to normal. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the loop on the question I opened, this turned out to be an issue with Orca Screen Reader becoming enabled by accident--which can be done from **outside** of a logged in session.